# Fetch results of joined tables as columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I trying to figure out a way to generate a SQL query, to be used in a view, to generate an Excel like format for parent-child relationship.

I have the following tables

###### Person

| id | name | email | accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | -- | -- |
| 2 | B | -- | -- |
| 3 | C | -- | -- |

###### Guest

| id | name | accepted | id_person (foreign_key -> person.id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AGuest1 | --- | 1 |
| 2 | BGuest1 | --- | 2 |
| 3 | BGuest2 | --- | 2 |
| 4 | CGuest1 | --- | 3 |
| 5 | CGuest2 | --- | 3 |
| 6 | CGuest3 | --- | 3 |

A person can have multiple guests accompanying him/her.

What I want to do is generate a SQL that gives me the following result:

| Person Name | Guest 1 Name | Guest 2 Name | Guest 3 Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | AGuest1 | -- | -- |
| B | BGuest1 | BGuest2 | -- |
| C | CGuest1 | CGuest2 | CGuest3 |

I can generate two separate queries that will generate a list of rows with that information but I am struggling to generate multiple columns based on the information that I have.

I have looked into crosstab() for postgres, but so far I have no luck with generating anything that would like this.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSSTAB`:

```
SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB (
    'SELECT p.name, g.name, g.name
    FROM person p JOIN guest g
    ON p.id = g.id_person
    ORDER BY 1,2')
    AS ("Person Name" varchar(100), "Guest 1 Name" varchar(100),
    "Guest 2 Name" varchar(100), "Guest 3 Name" varchar(100));
```

Please note: This will work for 1 to 3 guest like you described. In case more guests per person are possible, you need to extend this.

I created a working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8e666c917aaa0ef028abcb860dea8f46)

Comment: Is there any way to also include information like `accepted` from both the tables too?

Comment: Could you please create a new question with the new desired outcome? I think this will be easier to understand and follow.

Comment: Did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488293/add-columns-from-joined-table-to-crosstab-query