# Add columns from joined table to crosstab query

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I trying to figure out a way to generate a SQL query, to be used in a view, to generate an Excel like format for parent-child relationship.

I have the following tables

###### Person

| id | name | lastname | email | accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a | -- | true |
| 2 | B | b | -- | true |
| 3 | C | b | -- | true |
| 4 | D | d | -- | true |

###### Guest

| id | name | accepted | id_person (foreign_key -> person.id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AGuest1 | true | 1 |
| 2 | BGuest1 | true | 2 |
| 3 | BGuest2 | true | 2 |
| 4 | CGuest1 | true | 3 |
| 5 | CGuest2 | false | 3 |
| 6 | CGuest3 | false | 3 |

A person can have multiple guests accompanying him/her.

I can generate the following result using the following crosstab query:

| Person Name | Guest 1 Name | Guest 2 Name | Guest 3 Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | AGuest1 | -- | -- |
| B | BGuest1 | BGuest2 | -- |
| C | CGuest1 | CGuest2 | CGuest3 |

```
SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB (
    'SELECT p.name, g.name, g.name
    FROM person p JOIN guest g
    ON p.id = g.id_person
    ORDER BY 1,2')
    AS ("Person Name" varchar(100), "Guest 1 Name" varchar(100),
    "Guest 2 Name" varchar(100), "Guest 3 Name" varchar(100));
```

But I also want to include extra information from the table to the crosstab query, plus include person with no guests, so it gives the following result:

| Person Full Name | Person Accepted | Guest 1 Name | Accepted | Guest 2 Name | Accepted | Guest 3 Name | Accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aa | true | AGuest1 | true | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| Bb | true | BGuest1 | true | BGuest2 | true | -- | -- |
| Cc | true | CGuest1 | true | CGuest2 | false | CGuest3 | false |
| Dd | true | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |

- Using the table name in the value part of the crosstab, and specifying the column in the `as` part, throws an error
- Also trying to specify additional columns in the crosstab query also throws an error

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first assign a row number to each guest row by grouping on the person id. Then join back with the Person table and get each column relative to the number of guest and accepted value using the `CASE` statement. In order to remove the null values you can aggregate with the `MAX` aggregation function and group on the remaining columns.

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.name, p.lastname)                  AS PersonFullName,
       p.accepted                                  AS PersonAccepted,
       MAX(CASE WHEN g.rn = 1 THEN g.name     END) AS Guest1Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN g.rn = 1 THEN g.accepted END) AS Guest1Accepted,
       MAX(CASE WHEN g.rn = 2 THEN g.name     END) AS Guest2Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN g.rn = 2 THEN g.accepted END) AS Guest2Accepted,
       MAX(CASE WHEN g.rn = 3 THEN g.name     END) AS Guest3Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN g.rn = 3 THEN g.accepted END) AS Guest3Accepted
FROM       Person p
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT *, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_person ORDER BY id) AS rn
            FROM Guest) g
        ON p.id = g.id_person
GROUP BY PersonFullName, 
         PersonAccepted
ORDER BY PersonFullName
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tA7Y5YVDL8j2959Cb8JXfN/2).

Comment: This looks, interesting, but is only limited to 3 guests. Which is not a problem for me. But can you please look the desired solution again? I updated the tables. With both the approaches, mine and yours, I am not getting the person that has no guests, I want to include that too in the result

Comment: Just change inner to left join, try it now @VarijKapil. The fiddle is updated too.

Comment: A small remark: if you need more than 3 guests - or in general an indefinite amount of guests - you could use prepared statements that will allow you to generalize. If you would need such solution, ping me here. @VarijKapil